# Get total and average of minutes in each zone of exercise exertion

Tags: iphone, apple-watch, health.app, health-kit

I have an Apple Watch and iPhone with the latest OS software. I also have the Gentler Streak app.

These tools track my exercise including the intensity at each of the six zones, 0-5. I see these minutes in each zone while I am in a workout.

Is there a way to review the totals of minutes spent in each zone over a day, week, month?